# PHP group multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help with grouping multidimensional PHP array. The array I have is :

```
    Array
(
    [1385] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1385
            [product] => Tossed salad
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 489
                )
        )
    [1386] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1386
            [product] => Green salad
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 489
                )
        )
    [1387] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1387
            [product] => Milk Shake
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 440
                )
        )
    [1388] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1388
            [product] => Mango Juice
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 440
                )
        )
    [1389] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1389
            [product] => Orange Juice
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 440
                )
        )
)
```

I want to group the array in different way so I can list them categories. Something like this :

```
Array
    (
        [category_ids] => 489,
        [products] => 
          [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 1385
                [product] => Tossed salad
            )
          [1] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 1386
                [product] => Green salad
            )

        [category_ids] => 440,
        [products] => 
          [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 1387
                [product] => Milk Shake
            )
          [1] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 1388
                [product] => Mango Juice
            )
          [2] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 1389
                [product] => Orange Juice
            )
    )
```

The structure can be wrong because I just made it with my text editor. But yes I want something like this. List those products under `category_ids`, sometimes there could be more then one `category_ids` as well. There many other products fields also, I shorten to make it look less complicated. There are `product_price`, `company_id` and some has multidimensional array like `product_options`.

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: Unfortunately your requirements are not possible in PHP as a PHP array key **must be unique**. So you cannot have two `category_ids` keys in the same array. You could, however, use the category_id itself as the key, which would be unique for each category.

Comment: I was trying to break it down and create another array from it.

Comment: can you show the code you tried to write? It probably consists of nested ˋforeachˋ statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use this code to get your result

```
$array =  array(
    1385 => array(
            'product_id' => 1385,
            'product' => 'Tossed salad',
            'category_ids' => array(
                    0 => 489
                )
        ),
    1386 => array(
            'product_id' => 1386,
            'product' => 'Green salad',
            'category_ids' => array(
                    0 => 489
                )
        ),
    1387 => array(
            'product_id' => 1387,
            'product' => 'Milk Shake',
            'category_ids' => array(
                    0 => 440
                )
        ),
    1388 => array(
            'product_id' => 1388,
            'product' =>' Mango Juice',
            'category_ids' => array(
                    0 => 440
                )
        ),
    1389 => array(
            'product_id' => 1389,
            'product' => 'Orange Juice',
            'category_ids' => array(
                    0 => 440
                )
        )
);

$catArray = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['category_ids'] as $key2 => $value2) {
        if(isset($catArray[$value2])) {
            array_push($catArray[$value2]['products'], array('product_id' => $key,
                    'product_name' => $value['product']));
        }
        else {
            $catArray[$value2] = array(
                 'cat_id' => $value2
                );
            $catArray[$value2]['products'] =  array( 0 => 
               array(
                    'product_id' => $key,
                    'product_name' => $value['product']
                )
             );
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre/>';
print_r($catArray);
```